# ScrollView - Scroll still same position When I add elements in front of array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making chat app on react-native. I would like to take old messages When I scrolling up. when I scrolling up , I add elements in front of array but scroll still stop same position. But I would like to make like whatsapp.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FlatList` with [inverted](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#inverted) true. In `inverted` mode FlatList item will be shown from bottom to top. use `onEndReached` callback to load OLD messages into the array (data source of FlatList).

Example

```
...
<FlatList
   data={/*data source*/}
   renderItem={/*item renderer*/}
   keyExtractor={/*Key Extractor*/}
   onEndReached={this.loadOldMessages}
   onEndThreshold={0.5}
   inverted
/>
...
```

As per the above example `this.loadOldMessages` function will be called when all the items in the list are shown (user has reached the end), at this point you should pull new data (the old message) and add to the array.

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) instead of [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview).

**Example:**

`FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
   onEndReached={this.handleLoadMessages}
   onEndThreshold={0.5}
   data={this.messages}
   renderItem={(message) => <Text>{message}</Text>}
   inverted
/>
```

`handleLoadMessages`:

```
handleLoadMessages() {
  const generateNewMessage = () => `message: ${Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)}`;

  this.setState({
    messages: [
      ...this.state.messages,
      ...[
        generateNewMessage(),
        generateNewMessage(),
        generateNewMessage(),
        generateNewMessage(),
        generateNewMessage(),
      ],
    ]
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't want to this, I want to like whatsapp. When I get old messages , Content still same position but scroll goin down

Comment: @A.Emre Please describe Whatsapp functionality when getting old messages

Comment: when whatsapp get old messages , scroll going down and shrinking. But my scroll still stay same position. For example,
If(ScrollPositon <=50) getoldmessages();
after getoldmessages my scroll still position = 50, but Whatsapp not like this. scroll position going for example 150 and if dragging up , user can see old messages,

you can check on whatsapp